# Docker compose, it is possible to mount a folder inside an already mounted volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using compose for development I have my app mounted inside /var/www/html with this:

```yaml
volumes:
- ./app:/var/www/html
```

My local copy needs all the images that are in the production website, that are quite a lot so I don't want to store them in my tiny ssd but in a big extenal disk.

So my images are located in my /media/storage/bigdisk/images.

it is possible to mount this location inside the already mounted /var/www/html?

This way doesn't seem to work:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./app:/var/www/html
  - /media/storage/bigdisk/images:/var/www/html/images
```

Comment: it should work, inside the container is the directory present? also in the ./app have you got a directory called images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work normally, the only downside of this solution is that docker will create additional directory in `./app/images` - so it can mount images volume.

For this directory tree:

```
- app
--- index.php
- docker-compose.yml
- media
--- picture.png
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./media:/var/www/html/images
```

You get:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm app find /var/www/html
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/images
/var/www/html/images/picture.png
```

This works even when `./app/images` directory is present locally with some content. If it not exists then docker creates empty directory there with `root:root` persmission (if container runs as root).

Tested on `Docker version 1.12.6` and `docker-compose version 1.8.0`